# tailwindcss classes not applicable

Tags: npm, tailwind-css, npx

Until yesterday I was quietly working with tailwind css.

But today when I wake up when I open my vs code and try to add the utility classes, none of those classes come through.
I do not understand why !

I don't use the CDN, but I installed with npm.

I tried to close my vs code to open again, but nothing happens.
I was wondering whether to type the npx command every time I open my vs code.

Comment: Can you be more specific with your problem?

Comment: Please edit the question and some additional information.